# How to join table based on two column in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables as mentioned below.

```
user table
id  | username  | password  | status   |
1   | Prajna    | *****     | active   |
2   | Akshata   | *****     | active   |
3   | Sanjana   | *****     | inactive |

test table
id  | project_name   | created_by (user id) | edited_by (user id)  |
1   | Test           | 1                    | 2                    |
2   | Trial          | 1                    | 1                    |
3   | Pro1           | 2                    | 2                    |
```

I am trying with below query.

```
select project_name, user.username from test join user on user.id=test.created_by where user.status='active';
```

I wanted the result like below

**I want to retrieve the result as below
How can I retrieve?**

```
project_name   | username(created by) | username (edited by) |
Test           | Prajna               | Akshata              |
Trial          | Prajna               | Prajna               |
Pro1           | Akshata              | Akshata              |
```

Comment: It's highly implausible that you have a table with two identically named columns. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I have edited the question @Strawberry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code.

> ```
> create table `user`
> (
>   `id` int,
>   `username` varchar(20),
>   `password` varchar(20),
>   `status` varchar(20)
> )
> ```

> ```
> insert into `user` (`id`,`username`,`password`,`status`) values
> (1,   'Prajna',    '*****',     'active'),
> (2,   'Akshata',   '*****',     'active'),
> (3,   'Sanjana',   '*****',     'inactive')
> ```

> ```
> create table `test`
> (
>   `id` int,
>   `project_name` varchar(20),
>   `created_by` int,
>   `edited_by` int
> )
> ```

> ```
> insert into `test` (`id`,`project_name`,`created_by`,`edited_by`) values
> (1,   'Test',   1,     2),
> (2,   'Trial',  1,     1),
> (3,   'Pro1',   2,     2)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>   `t`.`project_name`, 
>   `ua`.`username` as 'username (created by)' , 
>   `ub`.`username` as 'username (edited by)' 
> FROM `test` `t` 
>   JOIN `user` `ua` ON `t`.`created_by` = `ua`.`id` 
>   JOIN `user` `ub` ON `t`.`edited_by` = `ub`.`id`
> WHERE 
>  `ua`.`status` = 'active' 
>   AND `ub`.`status` = 'active'
> order by `t`.`id`
> ```
>
> ```
> project_name | username (created by) | username (edited by)
> :----------- | :-------------------- | :-------------------
> Test         | Prajna                | Akshata             
> Trial        | Prajna                | Prajna              
> Pro1         | Akshata               | Akshata
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=085083242472b98344769c1ce54a498d)*

Comment: I don't have any syntax error. I had mistake while typing the question.

Comment: worked for me..:) Thanks for your help @alimbaronia and  2SRTVF

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   test.project_name, user.username
FROM test
INNER JOIN user
ON user.id = test.created_by
WHERE user.status='active';
```

PS: you have an error here user.id=**test=created_by**
.

Comment: I have edited the question with all the syntax error

Answer (score 0):

You need `sub-query` and join between those two sub-query using `join`

```
select project_name,created_by,edited_by from
(
        select u.id,project_name, u.username as created_by from user u left join test t1 on  
        u.id= t1.created_by   
       where user.status='active'
) Table1
   inner join
(

    select u.id,project_name, u.username as edited_by from user u left join test t2 on  
        u.id= t2.created_by   
       where user.status='active'
) table2 on Table1.project_name=table2.project_name
```